# How to print out the file name and line number of the test in python nose?

Tags: python, testing, nose, nosetests

When you are running tests in nose, I would like to display the filename and line number of the test itself, especially when it fails, on the command line so I can jump to the line in emacs. I have inserted some code into case.py to print out the name, I see that I could make a plugin that handles the prepareTestCase, but my question is is there a plugin that would do that?

here is my code : nose/case.py:

```
import inspect

...

def runTest(self, result):

 ...

 if not isinstance(test,Failure):
    print("  File \"%s\", line %s\n" % (
        inspect.getsourcefile(test.test),
        inspect.getsourcelines(test.test)[1]))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the filename of the test and test name just by running `nosetest` with `-v` option. In addition, tests that fail will dump a full stack trace on error (which has line numbers). You can also use `--pdb` and `--pdb-failure` options to get into pdb debugger immediately after error or test failure.

[Nose-progressive](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-progressive/) plugin has many bells and whistles in terms of formatting the output of the tests, including changing the template to satisfy any editor. Also, check out this [nosemacs](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/nosemacs/) - emacs extension to provide easy nosetest integration. And if you just want line numbers, [nose-machineout](https://code.google.com/p/nose-machineout/) is your friend.